# How can I prevent Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException on endpoints across 2 different webapis / domains?

Tags: c#, azure

Hello and thanks in advance.  We have been struggling with a
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException:

However, I cannot find any help as this seems to be a little different version of this error, the issue is across 2 different web apps:

they both live in azure

Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FCID.MAP.API.Business.Access.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
  public class AlwaysOnController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/")]
        public void AccessAlwaysOn()
        {
            // Root Url is used by Azure's "Always on" feature.
        }
    }
}
```

However 1 of the controllers is deployed to 1 web app, and the other controller is deployed to a different web app in the same azure resource group.

Has anyone seen this before or know how to correct it?

We have around 30 microservices as web apis, they all have similar controllers. However we are only receiving this error based on 2 of our apis..

Could it be that these are colliding somehow?

Here is the exact error message:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)

Here is the error message:

The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

FCID.MAP.API.Business.Migration.Controllers.AlwaysOnController.MigrationAlwaysOn (FCID.MAP.API.Business.Migration)
FCID.MAP.API.Business.Access.Controllers.AlwaysOnController.AccessAlwaysOn (FCID.MAP.API.Business.Access)

**However FCID.MAP.API.Business.Migration.Controllers
and
FCID.MAP.API.Business.Access.Controllers**

**live in 2 different microservice/web apis/domains/routes.
So I'm not sure how it would think there is duplication :(**

Comment: You must have 2 conflicting routes in the same asp.net program. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78030881/4139809 for the precedence rules. You can inject `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` to debug the endpoints metadata at runtime.

Comment: i believe them to be different asp.net programs is why i'm confused.

Comment: they are different web apps within the same app service plan, but i dont think that the plan should matter

Comment: Have you verified that it is actually a conflicting route and not just the lack of a route being specified in controller (and thus potentially have 2 different controllers resolve to the same route)? As per the docs, using the `ApiController` attribute makes attribute routing (`[Route]`) a requirement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#attribute-routing-requirement - right now, you most likely just have a generic `website.com/api/` endpoint that is used for the `AlwaysOnController`. Try explicitly specifying a route and seeing if that changes anything.

Comment: @nbokmans I believe that your theory about the lack of route being specified may have something to do with it, but there are a couple of issues here..  It is required that I have a route for the default/base route for each API.. So I cannot add anything to the route here, but if there is a better way to setup a default/base route please let me know!!  additionally we do have other duplicate subroutes across apis and they do not get flagged to your point... however we have THIS controller in other apis and they do not get flagged either only these 2 seem to collide somehow?

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect. You *must* have 2 conflicting routes. Now it's your job to find them.

Comment: the routes are on 2 different webapps...  how can they be conflicting, that's what I dont understand @JeremyLakeman

Comment: @JeremyLakeman i know the routes that are "conflicting".. so "now it's your job to find them"  is done.. i have found them. they are on 2 different web apps, that is the mystery.  It lists the 2 routes, i have no need to "find them"..  I am looking for more information.  Thanks

Comment: "I know the routes that are conflicting" I don't think you do. Your assumption here must be incorrect. You can only trigger that exception if you have 2 routes in the same asp.net program, with the same path. You need to debug the list of routes in these two web apps. I suggest, as per my first comment, you attempt to debug the routes that are actually discovered in each process. Perhaps something like  https://edi.wang/post/2020/4/29/my-aspnet-core-route-debugger-middleware. And if you can't remove the offending routes, try to tweak the precedence. Again, as per my first comment.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I have found the root cause and answered my own question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause!

[image]

The APIs incorrectly had a direct reference to each other.